# AngularJS - filter on a specific deep property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript object and want to use angular's filter on a specific deep property but it does not seem to work.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
 $scope.items = [
    {id:{val:1,str:'abc'}, name:'John'},
    {id:{val:2,str:'abcd'}, name:'John'},
    {id:{val:3,str:'xyz'}, name:'John'},
    {id:{val:4,str:'axcvb'}, name:'John'},
    {id:{val:5,str:'qwe'}, name:'John'}];

 $scope.items2 = $scope.items;

 $scope.$watch('search', function(param)
 {
    $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, {id:{val:param}},false);
 });
};
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lhhetazm/2/

If i just say,

```
$scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, {id:param},false);
```

Then it works but it searches the whole object which is not what i want, and i want it to work for partial searchs so i set the exact match flag to false

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to perform the filter on `ng-repeat`? Using `$watch`ing the `search` model seems like an overkill. ;)

Comment: No reason in particular, I actually wanted to know how to use filters on deep properties in the controller. This was just a sample code i found somewhere and modified. I just want to know if giving the second parameter like this, `{id:{val:param}}` in object notation is correct or is there some other way to use the inbuilt filter

Comment: I'll post something that might help

Comment: Ya it works great but for my actual project i need to use it in the controller, how do i achieve this. just saying `{id.val:search}` or `{id:{val:search}}` doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `$watch` from the Controller and perform the filter on the ng-repeat ...

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{id.val:search}">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you do this for a string instead of the search watch function?